# Which positive integers have at least one positive integer multiple such that the base 10 representation of that multiple has only even digits?

Tags: mathematics, number-property

Which positive integers N have the property that there exists at least one positive integer multiple of N such that the base 10 representation of that multiple has only even digits?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A067044

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The positive integers that have the desired property are**

> all of them.

**PROOF:**

> Let N be any positive integer.
>
> Let S be the N+1 element set $\left\{2, 22, 222, \ldots 2\cdot\frac{10^{N+1}-1}{9}\right\}$.
>
> Note the final element of S is the base 10 number 222...2 with digit 2 repeated N+1 times.
>
> When you divide positive integers by N, there are only N possible remainders which are 0, 1, 2, ... N-1.
>
> Consider now the remainders after dividing each of the numbers of the N+1 element set S by N.  Since there are N+1 computed remainders of S but only N possible distinct remainders, we know that at least two elements of S have the same remainder when divided by N (using the [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)).
>
> Let A and B be two elements of S (with A > B) with the same remainder R.
>
> We can express A and B as follows:
>
>   A=iN+R  and
>   B=jN+R
>
> where i and j are positive integers.
>
> A-B=(i-j)N.  So A-B is a multiple of N.
>
> But A-B is equal to the base 10 number 222...2000...0 where there are one or more 2s followed by one or more 0s.
>
> In conclusion, the positive integer A-B consists of solely even digits and is a multiple of N.
>
> Therefore every positive integer has at least one positive integer multiple such that the base 10 representation of that multiple consists of solely even digits.
>
> Q. E. D.

Comment: This proof is simpler.

Answer (score 13):

I think that the positive integers with this property are

> All of them

Proof

> First let $N$ be an integer which is divisible by neither $2$ or $5$.
>  Then, $\gcd(9N, 10) = 1$ and, by [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) $$ 10^{\varphi(9N)} \equiv 1 (\text{mod }9N) $$ This means that $9N$ divides $10^{\varphi(9N)}-1$ and $N$ divides $\frac{10^{\varphi(9N)}-1}{9}$ - a number consisting entirely of the digit $1$.
>  Hence, if $N$ is a number not divisible by $2$ or $5$, it has a multiple which is a [repunit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit).
>  Now suppose $N = 2^a 5^b M$ where $M$ is neither divisible by $2$ nor $5$ and let $c = \max(a,b)$.
>  Then there exists a repunit $P$ which is divisible by $M$ and so, $N$ divides $10^cP$ - a number which consists of just 0s and 1s in base 10.
>  Hence every positive integer $N$ divides into a positive integer which consists entirely of 0s and 1s, in base 10, and if we just double this multiple, we see that every positive integer also divides into a positive integer which consists entriely of 0s and 2s, in base 10, giving the result.

Comment: I was nearly finished writing up the same proof. +1

Comment: @JaapScherphuis great minds...

Comment: ...thinks alike, but fools rarely differ. [don't forget that second part of the quote! XD although I believe in this case only the first case applies]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> Every positive integer has this property.

Proof:

> Let $n$ be any positive integer and consider the sequence $2, 22, 222, 2222, ...$. Then, by the pigeonhole principle, two of the first $n+1$ terms (say, the $i$th and $j$th terms with $i>j$) have the same remainder when divided by $n$. Their difference is then a multiple of $n$ with only even digits (and in fact, it is $i-j$ $2$s followed by $j$ $0$s).

Comment: IMO, this adds **nothing** to @Will Octagon Gibson's self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

A sightly different solution here:

> All $N$s satisfy the condition. 
>  Assuming there's at least one $N$ whose positive multiples have all at least one odd digit, no number with all-even digits (let's call them "all-even numbers" or AENs) can be divisible by $N$. An AEN's multiples by powers of 10 are also AENs, but some of the remainders from division by $N$ will be the same thanks to the pigeonhole principle. We can add $N$ of these multiples with the same remainder whose non-zero digits won't overlap, getting an AEN divisible by $N$, no matter what $N$ is.

Comment: I think the first two steps are are not needed since your proof is not by contradiction and you don't use the fact that the remainders not all different.

Comment: Yup, I had a different idea in mind initially, so later deleted some stuff, but forgot to remove all those parts.